# How to use python keywords in model defing with Pydantic?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I want to define a model like this:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
     class: str
     pass: float
```

Since "class" and "pass" are python keywords this will fail.
Use marshmallow can do this by using data_key:

```
class Item(Schema):
    class_ = fields.String(data_key="class")
    pass_ = fields.Float(data_key="pass")
```

Does pydantic has something like "data_key" or there are other ways to achieve the same goal?Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

I can give you another option.

```py
class Item(BaseModel):
     class_: str
     pass_: float
     class Config:
        fields = {
            'class_': 'class'
            'pass_': 'pass'
        }
```